# Drawing a curved shape that bends along a curved trajectory

Tags: java, shapes, graphics2d, curve

So, I wish to be able to draw, for example, a raindrop in slow-motion that falls from the top of the screen. It's trajectory then changes from straight down and instead follows a quadratic curve towards the left. The tricky bit is that the raindrop's shape itself also bends in that direction to follow the curve. The image below roughly demonstrates the intended effect I want to achieve programmatically.

[image: Photoshopped raindrop following a curve in its trajectory]

If you want specific coordinates, let's say the path begins at 0,0 travels to 0,50, then curves to -15,100 where the control point is at 0,70. A typical raindrop shape can be achieved through two mirrored bezier curves as demonstrated in the image below.

[image: Raindrop approximated using 2 roughly mirrored bezier curves]

I know there's a way to derive points along a curve, which means I can derive the start and end points of the raindrop along it's curved path, but I don't know what to do with its control points. If I could derive the angle of the end-point's trajectory, I might find the answer by rotating the control points relative to that; but I'm not sure this is enough. The next step in the problem is what happens when the raindrop passes through several small curves in its trajectory. They can't all be summarised by a single bezier curve per side can they? (Not the Java kind at least, unless I'm missing something they only allow 2 control points). I can probably work this out given enough time, but I could definitely use some help coming up with a theoretical/algorithmic solution to this.

Is there anything already out there that tackles something like this?

Comment: The "typical raindrop shape" is not the shape of real raindrops - but I suppose you just want to create a gimmick?

Comment: You need a mapping of each half of the drop defined by the curve in the drop's undistorted shape, where you have points from top to bottom, P1,...Pn, into distorted areas left and right of the path. For a section of the path, compute the perpendiculars s1,...sn and map the points. Then, approximate using whatever Java provides.  I guess the effort depends on the way the path is defined, but basically it is a relatively simple exercise.

Comment: To see anything effective, the path must curve rather hefty compared to the size of the drop. The black shape in your Q is along a path that has already turned by 30° during the length of a single drop - two more and it'll fall sideways.

Comment: Well, this is just an example. I'll actually be drawing a much longer shape so the influence is more obvious. So you're suggesting I map points along the curved line of the raindrop, as many as required to be accurate, compute the perpendiculars of those points along the path, and then to draw the curves by deriving the control points again using a best fit algorithm?

Comment: Yes - that's the obvious approach. Neither curve (path, drop) is analytical, i.e., can be computed using a formula. Transforming points and interpolation is the way to go.

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: I never got around to implementing this, no. I can kind of understand how, but other projects took priority.